# Move a range of numbered files and change their value

Tags: linux, shell, mv

I've got numbered files (DSC_0001.jpg to DSC_0065.jpg), I know how to move them with `mv DSC_{0001..0065}.jpg dir`.

I have no idea how to move them and  change the range of values.

`mv DSC_{0001..0065}.jpg DSC_{0134..1198}.jpg` is not working.

Is there another way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script debugged and much improved thanks to
[Kamil Maciorowski](https://superuser.com/users/432690/kamil-maciorowski):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0065..0001}; do
  n="$(printf '%04d' "$((10#$i + 133))")"
  mv DSC_$i.jpg DSC_$n.jpg
done
```

Notes:

- We're counting backwards (`{0065..0001}`, not `{0001..0065}`) because numbers are about to be increased. The problem wouldn't hit you *in this particular case*, but imagine your range was `{0001..0150}`. Processing forwards, the very first `mv` would *overwrite* the file number `0134`. In this case it would be crucial to move files with higher numbers out of the way *first*, to prevent data loss. When moving to another (empty) directory (instead of just renaming files in a single directory), the problem doesn't exist.
- `10#$i` forces base-10 for this `$i` in shell arithmetic; without it a leading zero would trigger base-8, hence errors for numbers like `0008` which is not a valid octal number.
- `%04d` format in `printf` is responsible for leading zeros in the output (e.g. `0134` instead of just `134`). In this particular case `n=0$((10#$i + 133))` would also work, only because our `$((…))` yields a three-digit number each time.